# How do you uninstall VersalSoft?

Tags: uninstall, spyware

a collegue somehow managed to get some crazy applciation instaleld on their computer called VersalSoft Inc Internet Download 3.0.22.

Is this spyware? How do I uninstall it? I removed it from add/remove programs, but it still comes up. Even Revo Uninstaller can no longer find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you should take a look at the following, it can can be helpful

[image]

Comment: Where is the image from?

Comment: take look at this

www.seasonsecurity.com/versalsoft-internet-download-how-to-uninstall-it-76191 - 

i have given you useful part of it

Comment: was it helpful ?

Comment: hahahahahaha .... "To make absolutely sure I emptied my wastebasket" ... yeah, way to make sure ...

Answer (score 1):

This is what you describe [**Versalsoft Internet Download Software**](http://downloader.versalsoft.com/InternetDownload/)
Re-Check [**RevoUninstaller**](http://www.revouninstaller.com), it has been used to uninstall this software before.

Also check, [**VersalSoft internet download, how to uninstall it?**](http://www.seasonsecurity.com/versalsoft-internet-download-how-to-uninstall-it-76191)

Answer (score 0):

Try CCleaner at http://www.ccleaner.com/  It cleans the registry and purges the cache as well.

If the program is starting automatically check the startup folder or go into msconfig to check which programs are starting automatically.

Also you can look into spybot at http://www.safer-networking.org/en/index.html which will give you more control as to which apps start up.